# How to split a text file based on certain headers in Python and download audio files

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-requests

I have an input file that contains two types of headlines. First one is `[headline - ...]` which contains text information. Second one is `[date - ...]` which contains the url to audio file to be downloaded.

an example input would be

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OYNXf2i72qXIYP4asnPtzdMHp_AIcAlxxbjjuhkYK_4/edit?usp=sharing
```

So the purpose of this task is to split this text file by these 2 headlines. If it's `headline` I would like to store it into an individual single txt file with it's unique http link name in `texts` folder. For example, the first headline would be stored into `us-pompeo-06012020072305.txt` and would contain

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pwSOi4MuB3-WUs2d4KL-pfoyUx1_S_y-85VkHnQxWS0/edit?usp=sharing
```

and the next header which is `date` would be downloaded into `audios` folder and would be named `us-pompeo-06012020072305.mp3`

Important: If you see it, you will see that headline and date are not always after one another. Sometimes it's only headline, then date comes sometimes. And sometimes they come after one another.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if len(line.strip()) == 0:
            continue
        elif line.startswith("[headline"):
            continue
        elif line..startswith("[date"):
            continue
```

How do I complete this task?

Comment: where is headline and date in the given example? I can see only the URL.

Comment: Please paste the text of the input data in a code block (enclose within a pair of tripple-back-ticks: ```)

Comment: @Mandy8055 I could not paste it there because it was giving me an error. I used google docs instead.

Comment: @CypherX I tried putting it in there but it was giving me an error and would not let me post, so I put them in google docs

Comment: You might want to then post a smaller sample of the data.

Comment: @Mandy8055 So I need to only match for example ```us-pompeo-06012020072305``` the first one. Then append txt and mp3 when I process the files

Comment: @CypherX were you able to open my google docs? because it's complaining that I cannot use "" in the body

Comment: Updated the regex. Please check [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/IN7b9o/3) for headlines. Group 1 captures your requirement. I guess the link is static.Isn't it?

Comment: @Mandy8055 which link are you referring to?

Comment: @Mandy8055 also the regex, we don't want to capture anything before ```/``` the first one is good, but if you look at the second one it captures unnecesary information

Comment: **```https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/```** for headlines.

Comment: `/` can be adjusted @YuriBurkov. In my answer I'll adjust it. Just needs your confirmation whether it helps you or not?

Comment: @Mandy8055 yes it does! Thank you so much!

Comment: You can find the sample run [here.](https://repl.it/@mAndY80SS/demo) @YuriBurkov.

Comment: @Mandy8055 it doesn't save the article into files

Comment: @Mandy8055 yes! you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

You can try using `regex` (regular expressions) + `pandas` libaries to produce a table that has all the urls (headlines, date, mp3) and additionally another column: **`source_id`**. You could then use this `source_id` column to create the names of the `.txt` and `.mp3` files where applicable. Also, you could use the `mp3_urls` to download the mp3 files using the `requests` library.

Here is a Colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/sugatoray/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/answers/Q_62273183/Q_62273183.ipynb) with the complete solution:

[image: Open In Colab]

> The ***most challenging*** part here was to determine the regex pattern for extracting the headline-text blocks. Check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/P4cnOd/1). You will be able to understand what each part of the regex pattern does.
>
> **UPDATE**: There was a *headline-text-duplication* issue for every `source_id` in the last line. This was a bug, which has been fixed now. For clarity on how the regex pattern works see [this](https://regex101.com/r/t32hCF/2/).

### An example of regex-applied extraction of headline-text

[image]

#### Explanation of the regex-pattern

[image]

### 1. Code Implementation

Here we make the dataframe that has all the necessary information.

```py
## Define output directory
OUTPUT_DIR_HEADLINES = 'output/headlines'
OUTPUT_DIR_AUDIO = 'output/audio'

## Extract data and tabulate as a pandas dataframe
# Case: from text
#df = tabulate_headlines(text=s, filename="", verbose=1) 
# Case: from a file
df = tabulate_headlines(text="", filename="input.txt", verbose=1)
# Case: no text and no file (should return None)
#df = tabulate_headlines(text="", filename="", verbose=1)

if df is not None:
    ## Determine target rows
    target_rows_headlines = ~df.headline_text.isna()
    target_rows_mp3 = ~df.mp3_url.isna()

    ## Write headlines to .txt files
    print('Total headlines: {}'.format(target_rows_headlines.sum()))
    _ = (df
            .loc[target_rows_headlines, ["source_id", "headline_text"]]
            .apply(lambda row: write_headline(text = row['headline_text'], 
                                            filename = row['source_id'], 
                                            output_dir=OUTPUT_DIR_HEADLINES), 
                axis=1))
    print('Writing headlines to .txt files: COMPLETE')

    ## Save audio to .mp3 files
    print('Total audio files: {}'.format(target_rows_mp3.sum()))
    _ = (df
            .loc[target_rows_mp3, ["source_id", "mp3_url"]]
            .apply(lambda row: download_mp3(url = row['mp3_url'], 
                                            filename = row['source_id'], 
                                            output_dir=OUTPUT_DIR_AUDIO), 
                axis=1))
    print('Downloading audio to .mp3 files: COMPLETE')
else:
    print(f'df = {df} ... Cannot be processed any further.')
```

**Output**:

```
[7 rows x 5 columns]
Total headlines: 7
Writing headlines to .txt files: COMPLETE
Total audio files: 4
Downloading audio to .mp3 files: COMPLETE
```

**Output** of the dataframe: `df`

[image]

**Output** of the downloaded and saved information:

```sh
output
├── audio
│   ├── ear-state-06012020035108.mp3
│   ├── tw-uk-06012020113435.mp3
│   ├── us-pompeo-06012020072305.mp3
│   └── wang-06012020103828.mp3
└── headlines
    ├── ear-state-06012020035108.txt
    ├── hk-chan-06012020073718.txt
    ├── hk-innocent-06012020114634.txt
    ├── tw-uk-06012020113435.txt
    ├── us-pompeo-06012020072305.txt
    ├── us-wang-06012020135251.txt
    └── wang-06012020103828.txt

2 directories, 11 files
```

### 2. Code: Custom Functions

#### 2.1. Function for extracting information and tabulating it as a pandas dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
import requests

def tabulate_headlines(text="", filename="", verbose=0):
    """Tabulates the information from either a text string (text) or from the 
    text read from a file (filename) and returns a dataframe.

    Note: It was assumed that the paragraphs (headline text) will not 
    have any empty lines.

    Example:
        # Case: from text
        df = tabulate_headlines(text=s, filename="", verbose=1) 
        # Case: from a file
        df = tabulate_headlines(text="", filename="input.txt", verbose=1)
        # Case: no text and no file (should return None)
        df = tabulate_headlines(text="", filename="", verbose=1)
    """
    msg = f"No input provided. Returning {None}."
    if (not text) and (not filename):
        print(msg)
        return None # df = None
    ## Read text from input file
    if (not text) and (filename):
        # condition (not text) is equivalent to (text=="")
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            text = f.read()  
    if text is not None:
        ## Define regex patterns for 
        #  - headline-text and corresponding source-id
        #  - headline_url
        #  - date_url
        #  - mp3_url
        #  - source_id from (headline, date and mp3)
        headline_text_pat = r"\n?\[headline - https://.*/(.*?)\.html\]\n((.*\n)+?)\n"
        headline_pat = r".*\[headline - (https://.*?\.html?)[,\]]"
        date_pat = r".*\[date - (https://.*?\.html?)[,\]]"
        mp3_pat = r".*\n(https://.*?\.html/.*?\.mp3)\s*\n"
        source_id_pat = r"https://.*/(.*?)\.html" # headline, date
        source_id_pat_mp3 = r"https://.*/(.*?).html/.*?\.mp3" # mp3

        ## Compile regex-patterns for speed
        headline_text_pat = re.compile(headline_text_pat)
        headline_pat = re.compile(headline_pat)
        date_pat = re.compile(date_pat)
        mp3_pat = re.compile(mp3_pat)
        source_id_pat = re.compile(source_id_pat)
        source_id_pat_mp3 = re.compile(source_id_pat_mp3)

        ## Extract headlines (texts)  
        #  and store in a pandas.Series object: headlines
        headline_data = headline_text_pat.findall(text + '\n[')
        headline_texts = []
        source_ids = []
        for headline in headline_data:
            source_id, headline_text = headline[0], ''.join(headline[1:-1]).strip()
            headline_texts.append(headline_text)
            source_ids.append(source_id)
        # Save as a pandas.Series object: headlines
        headlines = pd.Series(data=headline_texts, index=source_ids)

        ## Extract the urls (for headline, date, mp3)
        headline_urls = headline_pat.findall(text)
        date_urls = date_pat.findall(text)
        mp3_urls = mp3_pat.findall(text)

        ## Make temporary dataframes
        df_headline = pd.DataFrame({'headline_url': headline_urls})
        df_date = pd.DataFrame({'date_url': date_urls})
        df_mp3 = pd.DataFrame({'mp3_url': mp3_urls})

        ## Process temporary dataframes to 
        df_headline['source_id'] = (df_headline['headline_url']
                                    .str.replace(source_id_pat, r"\1", regex=True))
        df_date['source_id'] = (df_date['date_url']
                                .str.replace(source_id_pat, r"\1", regex=True))
        df_mp3['source_id'] = (df_mp3['mp3_url']
                            .str.replace(source_id_pat_mp3, r"\1", regex=True))
        df_headline.set_index('source_id', inplace=True)
        df_date.set_index('source_id', inplace=True)
        df_mp3.set_index('source_id', inplace=True)

        ## Combine headlines, dates and mp3s together
        df = pd.concat([df_headline, df_date, df_mp3], axis=1)
        df['source_id'] = df.index
        df['headline_text'] = headlines
        df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    else:
        df = None
        print(msg)
    if verbose>0:
        print(df)
    return df
```

#### 2.2. Write headlines to .txt file and download audio files as .mp3 files.

```py
def download_mp3(url, filename='out.mp3', output_dir=''):
    if not filename.endswith('.mp3'):
        filename += '.mp3'
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    # update filename (add path if applicable)
    filename = update_filename(filename=filename, 
                               output_dir=output_dir)
    # write to mp3 file
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)

def write_headline(text, filename='out.txt', output_dir=''):
    if not filename.endswith('.txt'):
        filename += '.txt'
    # update filename (add path if applicable)
    filename = update_filename(filename=filename, 
                               output_dir=output_dir)
    # write to txt file
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)

def update_filename(filename, output_dir=''):
    if output_dir:
        output_dir = makedir(path=output_dir)
        filename = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)    
    return filename

def makedir(path):
    path = os.path.abspath(path)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    return path
```

### 3. Dummy Data

For some reason I could not paste the text from the sample input-file here. 
Hence, I filled in `some-text-here` whereever Chinese text was present. 
The [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/sugatoray/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/answers/Q_62273183/Q_62273183.ipynb) implementation has the original data in it.

```py
s = """
[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/us-pompeo-06012020072305.html]
some-text-here

[date - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/us-pompeo-06012020072305.html]
https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/us-pompeo-06012020072305.html/US-Pompeo.mp3

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/htm/tw-uk-06012020113435.html]
some-text-here

[date - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/htm/tw-uk-06012020113435.html]
https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/htm/tw-uk-06012020113435.html/tw-su.mp3

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/wang-06012020103828.html]
some-text-here

[date - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/wang-06012020103828.html]
https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/wang-06012020103828.html/wang.mp3

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/us-wang-06012020135251.html]
some-text-here

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/htm/hk-chan-06012020073718.html]
some-text-here

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/ear/ear-state-06012020035108.html]
some-text-here

[date - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/ear/ear-state-06012020035108.html]
https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/ear/ear-state-06012020035108.html/EarState.mp3

[headline - https://www.rfa.org/cantonese/news/htm/hk-innocent-06012020114634.html]
some-text-here
"""
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215670/discussion-on-answer-by-cypherx-how-to-split-a-text-file-based-on-certain-header).